# can't login to rate/accept despite being logged in

Tags: support, user-accounts

I am logged in (my name and a drop down of questions I rated/accepted in the past show up) but in the last few weeks every time I try to rate/accept I get a pop-up box to login.  I have tried logging in with my StackOverflow login, facebook, logging out/clearing cookies and even another browser I have never used before. Every time, it says I'm logged in, take me back to the page and...wants me to login again.  Any idea how to fix this?  I've tries this in both firefox and safari on mac.  This DID work for months in the past.

Comment: Are you talking about your SE account? This is definitely not WordPress related!

Comment: Site issues should be discussed on meta ... migrating ...

Comment: This looks weird, your account should not have "Unregistered" status when you add login details. I have pinged higher powers to take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what happened here, but it's fixed now.

Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: whoohoo, look at me marking things and checking things! thanks much!